# Mismatch function header

Tags: swift, swift3

```
 submitButton.addTarget(self, action: (self.submitButtonDown(_: , completion:  )), for: .touchUpInside)
```

results in `Expected expression in list of expressions`

function is

```
func submitButtonDown(_ sender: AnyObject?, completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
```

Should I include the closure inside for it to work?

Comment: You cannot use arbitrary methods as button targets. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425480/how-to-send-multiple-buttons-in-button-addtarget-action-swift3 for a very similar question.

Comment: Hmm that's kinda limiting, how would one go about attaching a completion closure on click (after function has run)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addTarget method is asking for a selector (not a block or function reference) so you cannot use it the way you're trying to.

The easiest way to trigger a callback on button tap is to assign the callback block to an instance variable and invoke that from a standard button tap handler.

```
var onTapCallback: ((success: Bool) -> Void)?

func submitButtonDown(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
    self.onTapCallback?(true)
}
```

Comment: Will this callback be called after submitButtonDown has finished running? I noticed that, an event doesn't end until the callback has been called as well...

Comment: Hey @Marin, yes. It's all chained up together as part of the event flow. Sorry for the delay.